# Reading sentences one by one beside a picture

Tags: android, open-source, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base, reading

I'm interested in android application with the following features.

It should enable reading a webpage with sentences which are played
one by one beside a picture.

The application should enable better focus and readability. It should
be optional to normal reading of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I programmed it myself, with the help of stackexchange users. It's [here](https://github.com/lucidl/tedegraph-mobile). It's implemented for reading Wikipedia articles.

You can read the sentences approximately one by one next to the picture.
There is a button `Fwd` (go forward one sentence) and `Back` (go backward one sentence).

You can add new Wikipedia article with the `New` button and then choose the article from the combobox (spinner). Every article can have one bookmark (where you ended reading).

Here is the link to the application in [google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tedegraph.tedegraph).

And [here](https://github.com/lucidl/tededroid) is the successor of the app written in Java.
[image: picture of the Tededroid app]

Comment: In the case of software recommendations, I believe the "link-onlyness" should be interpreted so widely as possible, but I suggest to write more about your solution.

Comment: @peterh I edited the answer.